# A good word for someone that is going to lots of big (global, local, folk) festivals?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a good word for someone that is going to lots of big festivals, but not partically limited to music, dance or something. Mostly like the national and local folk festivals. Thanks!

Comment: That's a party animal or a groupie.

Comment: _Party animal_ doesn't necessarily imply festivals, especially folk festivals.  _Groupie_ implies following a specific band or actor rather than festivals in general.

Comment: Are you planning on using this in a "color" article or a novel or something?  Are they traveling around like 'free spirits' , going from fair to fair as a lifestyle avoiding work etc?  "Gypsy" (although I'm not sure if that is PC), or even "bum" (festival-bum) might convey that lightheartedly.  I'm not sure if it would still work as "deadhead" is drifting out of our pop-culture but perhaps "Fest-head" could get the point across

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word in current use is *[festivalist](http://www.definitions.net/definition/festivalist)*:

> **festivalist**, *noun*: One who frequents or enjoys festivals.

*[The Festivalista](http://thefestivalista.com/)* is an online magazine for festivalists -- or *festivalistas*, which sounds better to my ears.

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is ***fairgoer***:

> ***[goer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/goer)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. *[in combination]* A person who attends a specified place or event, especially on a regular basis.
>      *‘churchgoers’*
>      *‘a filmgoer’*
>
> ***[fair (2)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fair#fair_Noun_500)***
>
> NOUN
>
> 1. A gathering of stalls and amusements for public entertainment.
>      *‘I won a goldfish at the fair’*
> 2. A periodic gathering for the sale of goods.
>
>    2.1 An exhibition to promote particular products.
>       *‘the European Fine Art Fair’*
>
>    2.2 North American An annual competitive exhibition of livestock, agricultural products, etc., held by a town, county, or state.

You could also use ***festival goer*** (or ***festivalgoer***)

> ***[festivalgoer](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/festivalgoer)***
>
> NOUN
>
> A person attending a music festival, film festival, etc.
>   *‘a cheering crowd of festivalgoers’*
>   *‘the majority of festivalgoers purchase tickets weeks in advance of the screenings’*

In the US, at least, *fairgoer* would likely make people think of a [state fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_fair) or a [county fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_show).  If that's not what you're looking for, [festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Festival) might be the better choice.

And lastly, if you *really* want to stress the notion of going to lots of festivals, you could use an adjective such as ***[professional](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/professional)*** (see #2.1) or ***[serial](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/serial)*** (again, note #2.1).

Of course, 50 years ago, that would have been ***[a deadhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadhead)***.  8^)

Answer (score 1):

How about **bon vivant**? The dictionary says it refers to someone who likes to go to parties to enjoy food and wine.

Comment: Interesting idea.  Could you edit and add a link to a dictionary definition?

Answer (score 1):

A **festival aficionado**

An aficionado is [a person who likes, knows about, and appreciates a usually fervently pursued interest or activity; a devotee (M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado)

Answer (score 0):

I you will accept two words,

***Festival junkie***

> Junkie: 2. One who has an insatiable interest or devotion: "a sports junkie." (*American Heritage*)

(I would define it simply as an addict.)